# Increase underscore

Tags: underscore

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

TLXV\rule{.5em}{.4pt}AAB % this looks better!
TLXV_2 % here the problem is that the underscore is too far downwards

\end{document}
```

Now in my opinion, the text-underscore looks too small, but maybe that's only due to the letter 'V' at the end. In my code editor, however, the underscore connects the letters much better (that means closer) with each other than in my pdf document generated by latex. Is there any way to improve on this? Possibly for the whole document?

Comment: You can add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but there will be no kerning against the V anyway.

Comment: @egreg thanks, I actually just found that one too. It looks better, but the underscore seems to be a bit too far downwards, at least from my perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `\textunderscore` character to be `.5em` in width instead of the default `.3em` by issuing `\DeclareTextCommand{\textunderscore}{OT1}{\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule width.5em}}`. Note that this will affect text as well as math mode. So, you can only redefine `\_` by issuing `\DeclareTextCommand{\_}{OT1}{\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule width.5em}}` and leave `\textunderscore` as is to be used in places of `_` as in the second example below. The `_` internally calls `\textunderscore`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%\DeclareTextCommand{\_}{OT1}{\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule width.5em}} 
\DeclareTextCommand{\textunderscore}{OT1}{\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule width.5em}}

\begin{document}

TLXV{\_}AAB

TLXV_2

TLXV\_a

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thanks, this is good, but it doesn't replace the underscore for the whole document (if it used for text as opposed to math mode)

Comment: @user3032689: Please see my updated solution.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Nicely done!